# Shift part of an image down in opencv (cut and paste)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a part of image and I want to shift it down say by 25 pixels like shown in the picture.

[image]

I have **mask** of the region I want to shift down. The total image size should not change. So, the operation is cut and paste. The region where I cut can be filled with 0 or 255.

Platform is C++

Answer (score 3):

Create two sub-images: the first `sub1` around the pattern you want to move and the second `sub2`, same size than `sub1`, around the destination. Copy `sub1` into `sub2` then fill `sub1` with black or white color. You need obviously to use the mask cropped at the same size than the two sub-images.

This is pseudo-code, to illustrate the idea:

```
cv::Mat YourImage;
cv::Mat YourMask;
std::vector<cv::Point> YourPatternContour;

cv::Rect sub1ROI = cv::boundingRect(YourPatternContour);
cv::Mat sub1 = YourImage(sub1ROI);
cv::Mat mask = YourMask(sub1ROI);

cv::Rect sub2ROI = sub1ROI + cv::Point(25,25);
cv::Mat sub2 = YourImage(sub2ROI);

sub1.copyTo(sub2, mask);
sub1.set(0, mask);
```